# On finite sums and products

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, products

I'd like to get a good book on *finite* summations and products before I study infinite series more in depth next year.  The book should cover geometric/ harmonic sums and prove different formulas for finite products.  Some geometric intuition thrown in with the algebra/ induction would of course be a plus.  Does anyone have a good recommendation?  If no such book on *just* finite sums and products exists then do you know of a good book which covers them as part of a broader topic?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, but just about any intro to combinatorics (enumerative combinatorics) would contain a lot of these kinds of things.  One book that comes to mind is "Discrete Mathematics and its Applications" by Rosen.  It is a text for intro proof writing (so it'll contain induction and the like) and will certainly see a lot of finite sums involving binomial coefficients (and it may help you learn to count).